# throttling http api calls with delay

Tags: django, rest, throttling

I'm trying to implement some throttles on our REST API. A [typical approach](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/throttling.html) is after a certain threshold to block the request (with `403` or `429` response). However, I've seen [one api](http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/faq/#faq6) that adds a **delay to the response** instead.

> As you make calls to the API, we will be looking at your average calls per second (c/s) over the previous five-minute period. Here's what will happen:
>
> - over 3c/s and we add a 2 second delay
> - over 5c/s and we add a 4 second delay
> - over 7c/s and we add a 5 second delay

From the client's perspective, I see this being better than getting back an error. The worst that can happen is that you'll slow down.

I am wondering how this can be achieved **without negatively impacting the app server**. i.e. To add those delays, the server needs to keep the request open, causing it to keep more and more request processors busy, meaning it has less capacity for new requests coming in.

**What's the best way to accomplish this?** (i.e. is this something that can be done on the web server / load balancer so that the application server is not negatively affected? Is there some kind of a throttling layer that can be added for this purpose?)

We're using Django/Tastypie, but the question is more on the architecture/conceptual level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your are using synchronous application server which is the most common setup for Django applications (for example a gunicorn with default `--worker-class sync`), then adding such a delay in the application would indeed have a very bad impact on performance. A worker handling a delayed request would be blocked during a delay period.

But you can use asynchronous application server (for example gunicorn with '--worker-class gevent`) and then an overhead should be negligible. A worker that handles a delayed requests is able to handle other requests while a delay is in progress.

Doing this in the reverse proxy server may be a better option, because it allows to easily and flexibly adjust a policy. There is [an external nginx  module for exactly such thing](https://github.com/perusio/nginx-delay-module).

Comment: Thanks! Looks like exactly the thing I was looking for (not sure which, but either would probably do).

Comment: Is that `nginx-delay-module` able to take instructions from Django in any way? For example if abuse is identified via Django views, can I instruct that plugin to delay the response on nginx's side? Ideally I'd like to write a custom Throttle class for DRF using this.