# Any out-of-box methods to implement request throttling in Java?

Tags: java, jboss, weblogic, throttling

Are there any methods or capabilities built in Java application servers (i.e. Weblogic or JBoss) or, probably, in load balancers (i.e. F5) to enable and configure HTTP requests throttling for my application?

Let's say, I have a Java web application with no throttling algorithms implemented in it. And I want to add a throttling feature to limit a number of requests to N per M seconds. One possible way is to use external (to my Java app) tools with such requests throttling abilities.

All I've found is about implementing own throttling mechanism in my application.

Partly similar questions:

- [throttling http api calls with delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15131671/throttling-http-api-calls-with-delay)
- [Throttling method calls to M requests in N seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1407113/throttling-method-calls-to-m-requests-in-n-seconds)
- [Best way to implement request throttling in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33969/best-way-to-implement-request-throttling-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: I would check if haproxy is capable of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't speak for JBoss but the Oracle Service Bus (optional add on to weblogic) can certainly do throttling if you set up your web service as a proxy/business:

About throttling:

https://blogs.oracle.com/knutvatsendvik/entry/throttling_in_osb

Installing OSB:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14571_01/doc.1111/e15017/apm.htm

Comment: Thanks, Oracle Service Bus seems to be the answer, I'll investigate it deeper.